# Probability that parallel lines

Tags: probability, geometry

a) Among all the lines determined by the vertices of the regular $ ABCDEF $ hexagon below, draw three distinct parallel lines, $ r, s, t $, and two competing lines, $ u $ and $ v $.

b) If two distinct lines are drawn from all the lines determined by the vertices of a regular hexagon, what is the 'probability' that parallel lines will be drawn?

[image]

Attemp: I found the number of lines: C (6.2) = 15. I found the parallels counting and found 9. Considering CD // EB

Correct?

Comment: You counted all the pairs, and then counted those that are parallel. What is your question?

Comment: There are 15 lines. But there are $\dbinom{15}{2} = 105$ pairs of lines. Out of the 105 pairs of lines, how many are parallel? Example, AB, CF, and DE are three lines, any two of which are parallel. There are three such sets of these (from rotations) and then you have AE and BD (and the three rotations of that). In total, there are $9+3=12$ pairs of parallel lines possible out of the $105$ total (assuming I did not miss any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\frac{6 \cdot 5}{2} = 15$ lines we can draw, and hence there are $\binom{15}{2} = 105$ pairs of lines. By simply counting, we find that there are $12$ pairs of parallel lines, so the probability is $\frac{12}{105} = \frac{4}{35}$ if we assume any pair of lines to be equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 15 lines. But you need to do a little more work. The 15 divide into 3 sets of 3 parallel lines and 3 sets of 2 parallel lines. The chance of picking first a line in one of the first 3 sets is 9/15. The chance of then picking a parallel line is 2/14. The chance of picking a line in one of the second three sets is 6/15 and you then have 1/14 chance of picking a parallel. So overall the prob is 4/35.